# Linux sys_uselib local root exploit

Tags: c, linux, kernel, exploit

I'm doing this interesting [experiment](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/895/). But it can be really complicated to understand. I got at least 2 questions.

- We have faked a VMA and msync_interval will get it as the comment says. But how does msync_interval get this fake VMA?
- Why does it need to consume a lot VMAs?

Many thanks in advance.

```
/*
* first create fake vma structs.
*
*
* let's have 3 threads, t1, t2 and t3.
* t1 and t2 have common vm.
*
* t3:
* - wait4sig (will come back from t2)
* - write(fd3, bigmem, bigfile_size)
* - exit()
* t1:
* - fd3 = empty file
* - fd1 = bigfile, writing it took 16 secs
* - bigmem = mmap(NULL, bigfile_size, fd1, 0);
* - t3 = fork()
* - t2 = clone()
* - fd2 = munmap_file, size of ram.
* - mumem = mmap(NULL, munmap_file_size, fd2)
* - mmap(mumem, 4096, ANONYMOUS) // for extending do_brk check
* - mmap lots of vmas
* - close(fd2);
* - create evil lib
* - free lot of vmas
* - sig @ t2
* - evil_lib->do_munmap(mumem + 4096, munmap_file_size - 4096);
* - sem = 1
* - waitpid
* t2:
* - wait4sig
* - sleep(100msec)
* - mmap(mumem, fd3, 4096) // this is being protected by i_sem !
* - sendsig @ t3
* - sleep(100msec)
* - if (sem) error
* - msync(mumem, 8192) - will wait for write() to finish. munmap finishes by that
* time
* - if (!sem) error
* - if it does return we failed, otherwise shell.
*
*/
```

Comment: cute, pseudo code.  however, that pseudo code could be implemented in many different ways.  Please post the implementation, then post what the expected output should be, then post the actual output.    Note: munmap() does not return until the operation is completed.

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for your reply. The implementation can be so long and complicated. Please check the link in my [post](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/895/) to find it. For the output: `msync_interval` will get a faked VMA and a dereference of a function pointer `file->f_op->fsync(file, file->f_dentry, 1)` will happen. Finally, get the root shell. I would really appreciate it if you could offer any help on how `msync_interval` gets the faked VMA and the reason for consuming lots of VMAs. Many thanks.

Comment: Please post (in the question, not in a comment) your definition of a 'VMA' and my system: ubuntu linux 14.04 does not have a 'msync_interval()' function, so I'm going to be of little help

Comment: I looked at the referenced code.   It seems your trying to by-pass the security of the database.   Not a 'nice' thing to be trying.    When looking at the referenced code,  There are a 'ton' of errors and readability problems.   Strongly suggest 1) do not follow this path unless officially testing the database.  2) leave out the nasty comments  3) indent the code, 4) separate code blocks by a blank line 5) check the returned value from system function calls to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the referenced code does not even come close to cleanly compiling, infact, it causes the compiler to raise several 'error' messages.  When asking for help with a runtime problem the posted code must cleanly compile, be of minimal size and still exhibit the problem.